# Split string to 2 parts when a specific character is found

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have a string from an API response from [launchlibrary.net](http://launchlibrary.net) which looks like this:

```
"Falcon 9 Full Thrust | PAZ & Microsat-2a, Microsat-2b"
```

The first part of the string is the name of a rocket and the second is the name of the mission.

I want to create 2 new strings from the previous string:

```
let rocketName = first part of the string before Vertical Bar Character -> |
let missionName = second part of the string after Vertical Bar Character -> |
```

Comment: You added the `split` tag... have you tried that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.split()`

```js
var inp = "Falcon 9 Full Thrust | PAZ & Microsat-2a, Microsat-2b";
var result = inp.split(" | ");
var rocketname = result[0];
var missionname = result[1];
console.log(rocketname);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = "foo | bar";
let parts = str.split("|")   // is now an array
let rocketName =  parts[0].trim()
let missionName = parts[1].trim()
```

Comment: some description to your answer would be nice ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

```
let response = "Falcon 9 Full Thrust | PAZ & Microsat-2a, Microsat-2b";
let result = response.split(" | "); 
//result = ["Falcon 9 Full Thrust", "PAZ & Microsat-2a, Microsat-2b"];
let rocketName = result[0]; //"Falcon 9 Full Thrust"
let missionName = result[1]; //"PAZ & Microsat-2a, Microsat-2b"
```